# Обработчик закрытия приложения

Tags: c#, winforms, события, handlers

Нужен event `handler` или любой другой способ получать состояние приложения, когда оно закрывается. Приложение без форм или консоли. Простая реализация через:

```
Application.ApplictionExit += new EventHandler(method);
```

не работает.

Comment: Что конкретно не устраивает в простой реализации?

Comment: У вас консольное приложение? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: У меня winforms, простая реализация не рабоает

Comment: А что конкретно означает «не работает»? Это может означать что угодно.

Comment: Ничего не происходит при закрытии